# Is it possible to open files with a single click in touch screen and with usual double click when using mouse?

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, mate, touchscreen, chromebook

I am using Ubuntu MATE 22.04 in a touch screen chromebook.

Is it be possible to open files and directories with a single click when using the touch screen, and with the usual double clicks when using the trackpad?

This seems to be the default behavior in KDE Plasma (even when double-click to open folders) is enabled. How to enable this in MATE?